# Vaadin TouchKit basic theming problems

Tags: java, css, netbeans, vaadin

I'm using Netbeans & Maven.
I have some problems using CSS with Vaadin Toolkit.
Some basic problems...

It seems to ignore every line of my custom css, I don't know why.

In "/VAADIN/themes/touchkit" I have 4 css and scss files.

> addons.scss styles.css styles.scss touchkit.scss

Basically, I wanto to change the background of a VerticalLayout or a VerticalComponentGroup.

So I've put

```
@import "../valo/valo.scss";
@mixin touchkit {
    @include valo;
    .backColorGrey {
        background-color: #0FD1B1;
    }
}
```

in touchkit.scss

and then

```
final VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();
final VerticalComponentGroup content2 = new VerticalComponentGroup();   
content.addStyleName("backColorGrey");
content2.addStyleName("backColorGrey");
```

Nothing happen.

I've compiled the Theme
I've tryed to put the code in the other scss files.
I've downloaded ruby to install Sass.
I've recompiled the Theme, the project, clean, clena &Build, recompile so many times ... and a lot of other action but the result is the same.
I've put this in the pom

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>j`enter code here`ava</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                <mainClass>com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/touchkit/styles.scss</argument>
                    <argument>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/touchkit/styles.css</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Nothing happen.
It seems to ignore any css line... but it is a so basic action!!!!
​It's frustrating, it is totally a waste of time.

Frankly I hate css.
Is there any way to set this value ignoring css by java code ? 
Like .setBackgroundColor ?

Comment: CSS styles must be defined in your styles.scss file, the sas compiler then generates the final css file for you

Comment: I've tried.
I've recompiled the theme.
Nothing...
Cleaned...rebuilded, recompiled... 
Nothing...

It seems to ignore any css.

Comment: Are your styles showing up in the final css file? In netbeans there is a special menu entry to just compile the scss -> css stuff. (At least when using the vaadin plugin for Netbeans)

Comment: BTW: Did you specify vaadin to use your theme? Somethings like @Theme("mytheme") in the UI class

Comment: I've "@Theme("touchkit")"
But " \src\main\webapp\VAADIN\themes\touchkit"

Comment: Have I to rename it ?

Comment: Via @Theme("mytheme") as mentioned here: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.creating.html, just make sure to inherit from the touchkit theme instead of valo or runo